# Documentation requirements for a baby for domestic air travel within India

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, india, airlines, children

I wish to travel domestically within India with my 9-month-old baby. What documentation do I need for a domestic journey? I don't currently have any documentation for my baby.

Answer (score 2):

Personal experience :

I think birth certificate would be sufficient.

Comment: It may even be necessary because airlines insist on it or else you need to pay full fare.

Comment: That still seems a bit unclear. Do you mean it is necessary but not sufficient (the baby needs something else), sufficient but not necessary (the baby could use something else instead), or both necessary and sufficient?

Comment: I mean it is sufficient... I do not know if it is necessary or not.... @mdewey

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer - This would depend on the carrier airlines.

[Bureau of Civil Aviation security](http://www.bcasindia.nic.in/law/AC%2015-2017-listofidproof.pdf) mandates no separate ID is required for infants/minors travelling with their parents.

The airlines may require an age proof to ensure infant qualifies for infant fare. If you don't provide a proof, you may need to pay full fare to travel. A birth certificate is universallly accepted (from experience).

[Indigo](https://www.goindigo.in/travel-information/en/infants.html) states you should produce one of these at check-in

> - Birth Certificate
> - Mother's hospital discharge summary
> - Vaccination certificate

[Air India](http://www.airindia.in/new-documents-to-carry.htm) has no such requirement:

> No identity proof is required in respect of Infant/Minor, when accompanied by their parents / guardian who is a traveling and having a valid identity proof as listed above. However, an unaccompanied minor must carry a valid identity proof as listed above.

[Go Air](https://www.goair.in/terms-conditions/) has no clarity. They just state age proof *may* be required.

[Spicejet](http://content.spicejet.com.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/TnC.html) is more stringent. They insist on birth certificate.

> Proof of age is required, so please carry the Infant's Passport/valid ID (birth certificate) for inspection

[Vistara](https://www.airvistara.com/trip/special-assistance/child-travellers) also requires valid ID but don't state what it is.

> If your infant is between 7 days and 2 years of age, they require valid ID